# Java P2P framework NOT JXTA/JXSE

Tags: java, frameworks, protocols, p2p

I need a Java framework to implement a simple P2P protocol which should have at least the following features:

- peer organization (join, discovery)
- XML message exchange
- query

I do not want to use JXTA/JXSE, any alternatives (a part from the DIY)?

Comment: Can you outline why JXTA is unsuitable for your needs?

Comment: @Matt yes, I need it to be P2P, I must limit as much as possible the presence of central servers

Comment: @halfer Firstly, the website at [link](http://jxse.kenai.com/) looks pretty much dead,Javadoc gives a 404 and tutorials are not completely working with the last version they where uploaded for (which is not the latest). I'm also on a very tight schedule so I do not have time to learn it from scratch

Comment: Glad you found something. Rather than editing your question, if you find the answer, add an answer at the bottom, and award yourself the tick. This takes the question out of our the 'unanswered' lists :)

Comment: @halfer ok, I'll keep that in mind for the future, cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP made an edit (now deleted by someone else) to say that [FreePastry](http://www.freepastry.org/) worked for them.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for a P2P java framework for about 12 months now.

I was reluctant to use JXTA for two reasons. Firstly it is quite complex even for setting up simple P2P sockets. Then literature is really poor. Finally there is no more development on it now.

That said, I did not find any other suitable alternative. Hence I learned JXTA.
I managed to get pretty much what I wanted even though I'm facing some tech issues and I will have to dive into JXTA source code to better understand why reliable streams are closed randomly.

I'm interested to understand if you find another framework.

Comment: @grog : i want to implement LAN messanger which is also using p2p concept. can i go for Freepastry for it ? I am having very limited time to implement it since it is an academic project. please share your views so that i can make proper decision.

Comment: @ankur.trapasiya: sorry I read your question only now. Yes I was happy with FreePastry and my network had to perform very basic message exchange operations so I'd say yes

Comment: Do you know better choice as of today?